# Why to put the WakeLock mechanism in BroadcastReceiver instead of having it in the Service?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, wakelock

I am having a look at the sample code from Google team for Android which is [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java)

My question is is there a specific reason to have this mechanism acquire/release in BroadcastReceiver instead of putting this inside the Service itself. If yes what is it
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very useful for something like alarms (see `AlarmManager`) or other types of `PendingIntent` use cases.  With alarms send to `BroadcastReceiver`s, the alarm manager mechanism ensures that the system will wake long enough to *deliver* the broadcast `Intent` (e.g. run the `onReceive()` method) to `BroadcastReceiver`s only.

If you were to use a `PendingIntent` for a `Service` in this case, the `Service` would get "started" from an API perspective, but would not necessarily run because the system could go right back to sleep.  Using a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, you could instead have the alarm trigger it, take the wake lock and start your `Service`.  The `Service` would then get an opportunity to run and would ultimately need to release the wake lock so the system could go back to sleep.

Comment: But is that possible that the service wouldn't start at all without acquiring a WakeLock?

Comment: It would *eventually* start, but would require the platform to stay awake before it would run its `onStartCommand()`.